# Standard shader will change from "Opaque" to "Transparent" at runtime but won't show any changes. Why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

It DOES change when I click on the dropdown box in the inspector, but that's worthless in an actual game. I'm guessing that I need to do something in my code to "refresh" the shaders but I can't figure out what that is.

```
public void MakeMaterialsTransparent () {

    // get all of the materials in an array
    Material[] materials = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().materials;
    Material[] newMats = new Material[materials.Length];
    for (int i=0; i<materials.Length; i++) {

        // copy the material
        newMats[i] = new Material(materials[i]);

        // set alpha for transparency
        newMats[i].color = new Color(newMats[i].color.r, newMats[i].color.g, newMats[i].color.b, 0.78f);

        // This SHOULD change the material to transparent
        // but it only works when I look at it in the inspector
        newMats[i].SetFloat("_Mode", 3);

    }

    // set the materials to the new array
    gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().materials = newMats;
}
```

Comment: check this out: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1004666/change-material-rendering-mode-in-runtime.html

Comment: but,  why dont you use the trtansparent always (with an alpha of 1 to make it opaque)ç

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1004666/change-material-rendering-mode-in-runtime.html

So, I got it to work by using this, but I'd still like to know why what I was doing was wrong.

Comment: ayy @Lestat I just found that answer
Anyway I'm not always using a transparent material because I don't know if the alpha value has any effect on the Opaque option at all, and it's supposed to be opaque most of the time.